# VueJs page is blank when using some wifi networks

Tags: networking, vue.js, dns, vuejs2, digital-ocean

I'm experiencing a weird behavior on my site. I hosted a Vue ssr application on a Digital ocean droplet, I have my domain name registered with Godaddy. The Godaddy domain name was first of all pointing to a different server, I then change to dns of the domain to point it to the digital ocean droplet. Every was working fine but it stop working on it's own after some time. The domain, example.com, was now displaying a page with a red car on it (that's not my website), and the sub-domain vuejs.example.com, was loading a blank page.

I disconnected from the wifi network I was using, xxx, and connected to an other wifi network, yyy, the site works perfectly with the yyy network but 
still didn't work with the xxx network.

This morning when I got up I tried accessing the site again with the xxx network and it worked but the vuejs.example.com sub-domain doesn't still work. When I open the sub-domain I get a blank page but the title of the vuejs application and the favicon are displayed normally.

Note:

1: If I change the network, the sub-domain where my web app runs will work perfectly (vuejs.example.com)

2: Using xxx network, all other sites open, so the problem is not with the Internet connection

3: I asked to friends to try to access the sub-domain, vuejs.example.com, where the vuejs app is hosted; those who accessed using the same internet provider as xxx network also had the blank page. Those who used different internet providers could open the vuejs app with no problem.

I'm sorry for the english, please let me know if something is not clear. I hope I can find a solution here.

**Edit: ** I have just noticed that certain files could not be loaded on this network but I don't know why.

[image: screenshot of network console in chrome]
[image: screenshot of response for certain request]

All the files with response 304 are not loaded.

Comment: It can take up to 3 weeks for certain ISP's to update their DNS. It's a shitty truth.

Comment: But it was working some fews minutes after I changed the DNS

Comment: And if you read my entire question you will see that the page actually opens but it's blank

Comment: the page title and the favicon are showing

Comment: Have you tried running `ipconfig /flushdns`?

Comment: Does your router for network xxx have custom DNS settings? Try changing them in the router to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: @SimonHyll thanks for your contribution, I'm on mac and I ran the command: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to flush my dns cache but it didn't work

Comment: I finally deleted the digital ocean droplet and created a new one. The new droplet works fine but i'm still wandering why this one had this issue.